# MS Access DCount validation

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I am trying to validate a product code when entered in a textbox. I can't seem to figure out a way to throw up a message box saying nothing was entered.

```
Me.txt_Product = UCase(Me.txt_Product)

If Not IsNull(upProd) Then
    If DCount("Validation_Test", "Validation_Testing_Table", "[Validation_Test] = '" & UCase(Me.txt_Product) & "'") >= 1 Then
        MsgBox "User Name Found!"
    ElseIf Me.txt_Product.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "You Did Not Enter a Product Code!"
    Else
        MsgBox "User Name Not Found!"
    End If
End If
```

Any suggestions for help with the DCount or other ways to do this?

Comment: What is upProd? If this is a variable, how is it declared and populated? Why repeat the UCase() conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect textbox is Null and testing for an empty string fails. Handle possibility of either Null or empty string:

`ElseIf Me.txt_Product.Value & "" = "" Then`

Concatenating Null with "" (empty string) returns empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a better logical flow:

```
Me!txt_Product.Value = UCase(Me!txt_Product.Value)

If Not IsNull(upProd) Then
    If Nz(Me!txt_Product.Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "You Did Not Enter a Product Code!"
    Else
        If IsNull(DLookup("Validation_Test", "Validation_Testing_Table", "[Validation_Test] = '" & Me!txt_Product.Value & "'")) Then
           MsgBox "User Name Not Found!"
        Else
           MsgBox "User Name Found!"
        End If
    End If
End If
```

And be careful with all those exclamation marks. Users will understand the message without being yelled at.